Unable to use X11/xorg in ubuntu 24.04
Ubuntu 24.04 works good in wayland but when i try to open ubuntu in x11 mode during login time it stays in the login page only and also when i try to change it manually in the /etc/gdm/custom.conf system crashes

does this resource answer you question?

when i run this command systemctl status display-manager i got
Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Gdm: Child process -1315 was already dead.

Actually this issue is in oracle virtualbox 7.0

Did you update /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and set WaylandEnable=false?

@graham No it doesn't, cause switching a DM is a different operation from subj.

@PrajwalBhopale Yes, it's a problem with VirtualBox, check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1536250/disabling-wayland-permanently-under-ubuntu-24-04-1-lts-doesnt-work
