Disabling Wayland permanently under Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS doesn't work in VirtualBox
I very well know that to permanently disable Wayland in order to use Xorg it is sufficient to run:
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

and to uncomment the line:
#WaylandEnable=false

If I do this under Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and then reboot, then I end up with a black screen instead of the login screen.
There is this discussion on Reddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1coyrc2/2404_has_anyone_been_able_to_disable_wayland/
and in one of the comments at the bottom the topic starter even said that he'd resolved the problem but without giving any detail on which service file he edited.
It has also been addressed here:
On 24.04 setting waylandEnable=false does not work, still uses Wayland, I want to use Xorg
but the answer provided by the question author himself doesn't help me either.
I've also tried to replace gdm3 with lightdm or sddm, but after entering my password at the login screen I get thrown back at the login screen.
Is there a way to resolve this problem at all? It wasn't present in the previous Ubuntu releases! I need to disable Wayland permanently, because it is a remote unattended computer, and most of the remote control software (TeamViewer, Anydesk and Rustdesk in my case) don't support Wayland.
EDIT:
This issue is also present in Ubuntu 24.10, I've just tested it.
BTW, I'm not sure, but just in case: all of this testing I'm doing on a virtual machine in VirtualBox. Could this be the source of the problem?

I do not understand the problem. When you select Xorg or Wayland on a properly functioning Ubuntu Desktop system, it remembers your choice. You don't need to keep choosing every time. You only choose once, and then forget about it.

@user535733 Then read the question again to understand the problem. I said: after rebooting there is a black screen instead of the login screen. Hard to forget about that one.

You wrote that you get a black screen if you uncomment a config line. But you're not asking about that breakage. You're asking how to do something that gdm already seems to do for most users. That's curious, and suggests a possible XY Problem. A clarification might help folks here to provide more useful answers.

Try adding the line DefaultSession=gnome-xorg.desktop under WaylandEnable=false.  Ensure that both lines are in the [Daemon] section of the /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file.

@user535733 Once again: read the question carefully and completely. It has nothing to do with gdm, because the problem persists with other display managers, too. Under Ubuntu 22.04 this problem doesn't arise at all under the same conditions.

@noisefloor Unfortunately, this doesn't help.

Yes! As I guessed in the "EDIT" section of my question, it is really a problem of the VirtualBox!
I've just stumbled across this post about Xorg not working in Ubuntu 23.04:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2486167&p=14145942#post14145942
then I've enabled "3D acceleration" (in VirtualBox: select your virtual machine, click on "Settings", select "Display", on the tab "Screen" check the box "3D acceleration"), and now I can login with permanently set Xorg, and there is no need to uncomment #WaylandEnable=false in the /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file, you just have to select "Ubuntu on Xorg" under the gear wheel icon during the login once and it remains set permanently. So, at least we know now the source of the problem with Xorg and it is resolved now.
BUT! Yes, there is always a "but". Strangely enough, Ubuntu 24.X will not login on Xorg if you use the dark theme! This has been reported here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1cdrys3/xorg_and_dark_theme_doesnt_work_on_2404_for_me/
and I can confirm this, just as much as I can confirm the solution mentioned there, that is, add a new line
ADW_DEBUG_COLOR_SCHEME=prefer-dark
in
/etc/environment
But this solution worked for me only in Ubuntu 24.04.1 and doesn't in 24.10 (both tested only in VirtualBox!).
UPDATE
Instead of enabling "3D acceleration" you can also leave it un-checked and in the "Graphics Controller" drop-down menu select "VBoxSVGA" instead of "VMSVGA". This solution is better from the point of view, that you will not have the other problem with the dark theme, too! (Tested only  in Ubuntu 24.04.1.)
